# How to install VPN on Ubuntu 18.04 in China

Tags: internet, vpn, connection

I am a student in China it has been 2 weeks I am here and tried to install several VPNs on my laptop, but I couldn't. I would be glad if anyone shared with their experiences about how to tackle with this problems!

[image][image]

Comment: oops sorry to hear what your going through, xD may i ask what have you tried first? without posting your problems like errors/debug logs you faced we can't possibly help you out!

Comment: first you need to know what VPN you are connecting to, then you need to know which software you need to use to connect to it (OpenConnect, OpenVPN, etc)  If you are asking how to get around the great firewall of china, that question may violate the sites terms.

Comment: in china many sites are blocked and i tried to install openvpn and nordvpn expressvpn all of them need to be downloaded and their sites are blocked too because i couldn't access their sites

Comment: @JKarshiev It’s not enough to just download a VPN client, you also need to have access to a VPN server as well. If you’re having problems installing a VPN client, please post the error messages that you get.

Comment: Many common VPN services work perfectly well through the default VPN client already included with Gnome. No additional software needed.  System Settings --> Network

Answer (score 1):

Try the TOR Browser and you will be able to download from the websites that are otherwise blocked.

Here is the [download link](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) to install Tor Browser.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens With TOR Browser the OP will be able to download from the websites that are otherwise blocked. But this is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: The Tor website itself is often (always?) blocked in China, so this may not be helpful.